# How to search for bytes in Queue<byte> and extract packet?

Tags: c#, list, serial-port

I'm receiving packets over COM port. Each packet begins with {0xFF, 0xFF} and ends with {0xFE, OxFE}. All received bytes are queued in `Queue<byte>` and after each `void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)` I'm processing that queue.
If any 0xFF or 0xFE shows up in packet, device add 0x00 after it.

1. How to extract each packet?
2. How to delete unnecessary 0x00 inside each packet that have header byte inside?

For the first issue I have:

```
void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[port.BytesToRead];
    try
    {
        port.Read(data, 0, data.Length);    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    data.ToList().ForEach(newByte => receivedData.Enqueue(newByte));
    processData();
}

private void processData()
{
    // Determine if we have a "packet" in the queue
    if (Enumerable.SequenceEqual(receivedData.Take(2), new List<byte> { 0xFF, 0xFF }))
    {
        // Beginning of new packet in the front of queue is ready!
        if (Enumerable.SequenceEqual(receivedData.Skip(Math.Max(0, receivedData.Count() - 2)).Take(2), new List<byte> { 0xFE, 0xFE }))
        {
            List<byte> tempPacket = new List<byte>();
            // Whole packet in the queue
            while(receivedData.Count > 0)
                tempPacket.Add(receivedData.Dequeue());
            tempPacket.TrimExcess();
            Packet pack = new Packet(tempPacket, PacketOrigin.Serial);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to remove all 0x00 that are after any 0xFE and 0xFF that can be found inside `Queue<byte>` so far I came up with:

```
List<byte> unconvertedPacket = new List<byte> { 0xFF, OxFF, 0x00, 0x00,0x4D, 0xFA 0xFE, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03, 0xFE, 0xFE}
int index = 0;
while (index != null)
{
    unconvertedPacket.RemoveAt(index + 1);
    index = unconvertedPacket.IndexOf(0xFE);
}
while (index != null)
{
    unconvertedPacket.RemoveAt(index + 1);
    index = unconvertedPacket.IndexOf(0xFF);
}
```

Does anyone have maybe any other solution/advice for doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach:

In the DataReceived event handler keep reading the incoming data and append it to a buffer (byte[]).

First you need to find the start marker ({0xFF, 0xFF}) in the buffer of received data. You need to determine the index of this marker within the buffer.

Once you have the start index, you need to keep appending incoming data to the buffer and check if the end marker (0xFE, 0xFE) has arrived. Capture the index of the end marker within the buffer.

Once you have the start and end index you can extract the packet between them. Nevermind about the extra 0x00 byte that gets added after it. You know the index of the start and end marker and their length (2). Just extract the array of bytes between them.

You need to create a search algorithm to suit this purpose. Both the needle and the haystack are an array of bytes (byte[]). You can use the [Boyer-Moore string search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) for this purpose.

Here's a simple C# implementation of the Boyer-Moore algorithm which only implements [the bad character rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm#The_Bad_Character_Rule). Read up on Wikipedia if you also want to implement the [good suffix rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm#The_Good_Suffix_Rule).

The algorithm is normally intended for strings, but I modified it to work with byte arrays. Tested this locally with an IP camera to extract the received JPEG images.

Check out the Wikipedia article for more information about it. It contains a full Java implementation which you can easily translate to C#.

```
public class BoyerMoore
{
    public static int IndexOf(byte[] needle, byte[] haystack)
    {
        if (needle == null || needle.Length == 0)
            return -1;

        int[] charTable = CreateCharTable(needle);
        for (int i = needle.Length - 1, j; i < haystack.Length;)
        {
            for (j = needle.Length - 1; needle[j] == haystack[i]; i--, j--)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                    return i;
            }
            i += charTable[haystack[i]];
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private static int[] CreateCharTable(byte[] needle)
    {
        const int ALPHABET_SIZE = 256;
        var table = new int[ALPHABET_SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Length; i++)
        {
            table[i] = needle.Length;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < needle.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            table[needle[i]] = needle.Length - 1 - i;
        }
        return table;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
var haystack = new byte[] 
  {0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4D, 0xFA, 0xFE, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03, 0xFE, 0xFE};

var startIndexOf = BoyerMoore.IndexOf(new byte[] {0xFF, 0xFF}, haystack);
var endIndexOf = BoyerMoore.IndexOf(new byte[] {0xFE, 0xFE}, haystack);

var packet = new byte[endIndexOf - 2 - startIndexOf];
for (int i = startIndexOf + 2, j = 0; i < endIndexOf - startIndexOf; i++, j++)
{
    packet[j] = haystack[i];
}
```

Voila, the packet byte array contains 9 bytes in this example and only contains the bytes between the start and end marker. You can now trigger an event and pass the packet as an event arg for example.

**Remark**: Receiving the data from the COM port is a continuous event. You need to keep monitoring it. Keep appending the received data and keep checking for the start -and index markers, extract the packages...etc. Watch out that your buffer does not overflow. You need to implement some housekeeping there.

Hope it helps. Check out [AForge](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/) implementation of an [MJPEGStream](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/source/browse/trunk/Sources/Video/MJPEGStream.cs) for an example of continuously reading incoming data.

To recapitulate:

1. Declare an instance variable to store the received data (e.g. _buffer = new byte[4096]).
2. Append the incoming data to the buffer in the DataReceived event handler.
3. Search for the start marker. If found remember the start index in an instance variable.
4. If you already know the position of the start marker, then search for the index of the end marker.
5. When you find the end marker, extract the packet and fire an event. Use the packet as part of the event's EventArgs.
6. Wash, rinse, repeat.

You need to implement some housekeeping to make sure the buffer won't overflow (> 4096 bytes). For instance once you find a packet you can clean up the buffer up until the last received end marker.

Comment: Your approach is good until not whole packet will show up on DataReceived event. If only part of packet, i.e. head and some data without '0xfe, oxfe' tail will come and in the second dataReceived event rest will come, previously received data will be overwritten and lost. That's why I used queue and dequeue method.

Comment: I don't expect the whole packet to arrive at once. When you read data from the port, add it to a buffer, which you declare as an instance variable, not a local variable of the event handler. Updated my answer.